# How do I redirect two domains to another domain with Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have three domains, two of which are supposed to be redirected to the other.

www.example.com
www.example.net
www.example.org

I already have the DNS entries setup so that they all will go to the same IP address.

What I want to have happen is for the .com and .net urls to be permanently redirected to the .org address. So:

http://www.example.com -> http://www.example.org
http://www.example.net -> http://www.example.org
http://example.com -> http://www.example.org
http://example.net -> http://www.example.org

In my .htaccess file I have the following configuration which I setup from the best of my understanding of http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Theoretically, what should happen is that any requests to the site where the HTTP_HOST is *not* www.example.org, then it should be permenantly redirected to http://www.example.org/ followed by any original path that was on the URL.

I'm sure this is easy to do and I'm just missing something obvious, but it seems like all of the other questions and search results talk about redirecting subdomains and file paths, but none of them talk about redirecting a top level domain in a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Thats almost the same that I use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www.example.org$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was on the right track. My final code wound up being this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The root of the problem for me was that my host was unaware I had multiple domains. So when requests would come into the site after being resolved, the host would throw up a page saying there it couldn't find a site. So I added my example.com and example.net sites to my host and parked them to example.org.

Perhaps somebody else can better explain what happened here than I, but the real issue was not with the rewrite but with my hosting provider.